# Need to be converted these two JavaScript functions into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is sample of two JavaScript functions, addRow which adds table row and deleteRow which deletes checked row of a table. How can I convert it into jQuery?

```
   function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = $("#dataTable");//document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox";
    element1.onclick= function () {toggleCheckbox(this)};
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }


    }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: create a sample jsfiddle so people giving answer can test their answers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbw9sm7s/
check this jsfiddle file. by clicking on "Add Row" button there will be a popup to take first name and last name. After submitting it, a row with the same input will be inserted in the table with check box.

now to delete the row, user will select a row from the check box and click on "Delete Row" it will be simply deleted. 

no Database interaction needed for this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there is no need to convert ,
still if u want to

```
function addRow(tableID) {

var table = $("#dataTable");//document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.appendChild('<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" onclick="function ({toggleCheckbox(this)}">');

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.html($("#fname").value);

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell3..html($("#lname").value);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
try {
var table = $('#'+tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }


}
}catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

}